# Is there a simpler way to write this if/else statement without a variable?

Tags: javascript

I have a quiz with one input. On the first enter press, it grades the answer. On the second enter press, it resets a new question.

1. Is there a simpler way to write this without the `flip` variable?
2. If not, is there a way to include the variable inside so that I could export the function as a whole?

```
var flip = true;

document.getElementById("guess-input").addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (flip === true) {
      flip = false;
      check();
    } else {
      flip = true;
      reset();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a data-attribute or a class

```js
document.getElementById("guess-input").addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    event.preventDefault();
    const tgt = event.target;
    if (tgt.matches(".flipped")) check();
    else reset();
    tgt.classList.toggle("flipped")
  }
});
```

Comment: This is working well, thank you! Would it be best practice to hardcode 'class="flipped"' in the HTML document, or should the JS handle it alone?

Comment: There is no need if NOT flipped is default state

Answer (score 0):

I think nicer and more usable will be a class on input (you can use more questions in one page).

Just on first enter add class to an input for example "validated" and on another enter you check the class and when there will be "validated", you can reset the question and class.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer as code example

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for feedback I will include it next time

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to keep the code the same you could use [a closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) - essentially move your variable inside the function but have that function return a *new* function that the listener calls when the event is triggered. This works because the returned function carries with it references to its "outer lexical environment" which, in this case, is the `flip` variable.

```
export default function guesser() {
  let flip = true;
  return function (event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (flip === true) {
        flip = false;
        check();
      } else {
        flip = true;
        reset();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

And then in your main code:

```
import guesser from './guesser';

const el = document.getElementById('guess-input');

// Call the guesser function which returns that inner
// function which the listener calls when the event is triggered
el.addEventListener('keyup', guesser());
```

Comment: Yikes. I find that real overkill... Also it is tricky since you now NEED the () on the function in the callback

Comment: Oh, give me a break with the melodrama. We were presented with two options. I went with option 2. @mplungjan

Comment: Just an opinion, no melodrama intended

Answer (score 0):

We can have some fun with it and set a new listener at the end of the first one, while making our listeners run only once.

```js
const input = document.getElementById("guess-input") // to keep it neat
const options = {once: true}

function checker(e){
  if (e.key !== 'Enter') return
  e.preventDefault();
  check();
  input.addEventListener('keyup', resetter, options);
}

function resetter(e) {
  if (e.key !== 'Enter') return
  e.preventDefault();
  reset();
  input.addEventListener('keyup', checker, options);
}

input.addEventListener("keyup", checker, options)
```

You can also do it by reassigning the `onkeyup` handler which overwrites the original callback:

```js
const input = document.getElementById("guess-input") // to keep it neat

function checker(e){
  if (e.key !== 'Enter') return
  e.preventDefault();
  check();
  input.onkeyup = resetter;
}

function resetter(e) {
  if (e.key !== 'Enter') return
  e.preventDefault();
  reset();
  input.onkeyup = checker;
}

input.onkeyup = checker;
```

This is just a different approach to the problem. The data attribute approach is perfectly valid.